# Missing "new web site" option in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, web

Why is that I can open a Web Site using Visual Studio 2019 Professional but I can't create one? I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.0.4. I can create a new site in VS 2015 and then open it in VS 2019, but there must be an easier way.

I have checked all the menu options but cannot find a way to create a new website like I can in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: It should have been deleted since 2005, when they first introduced ASP.NET Web Application.